# Most general second-rank symmetric tensor in Einstein theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature

I am reading [MTW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation_%28book%29) page 407, Exercise 17.1.

> (a) Show that the most general second-rank, symmetric tensor constructable from ***Riemann*** and $g$, and linear in ***Riemann***, is
>   $$a R_{\alpha\beta} + b R g_{\alpha\beta} + \Lambda g_{\alpha\beta}\tag{17.10} $$
>   where $a$, $b$, and $\Lambda$ are constants.

How can I show this statement? 
The overall stuff in GR, the possible two rank symmetric tensor are $g_{\alpha\beta}$ and $R_{\alpha\beta}$ (as far as I know) so their linear combination might be nice guess, but i think it is not enough for proving such statement.

Comment: You could also include higher-order terms, i.e. terms like $g_{\mu \nu} R^2$, $g_{\mu \nu} R^{\alpha \beta} R_{\alpha \beta}$, etc. But once you include those you aren't talking about GR anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a contraction between $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ and any number of $g$:s, such that the resulting tensor has two indices. Without loss of generality we can assume that each $g$ is contracted with $\text{Riemann}$ on both indices or not at all, and that no $g$ is contracted with another $g$. The first is because contracting once just raises an index, the second because contracting $g$:s with each other either produces a constant or a new $g$. Thus the only possibilities are $$R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma}g_{\alpha\beta}$$
and $$R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}g^{\nu\sigma}.$$
Strictly speaking, we should include also the tensors corresponding to permuting the indices on $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$, but by the symmetry properties of the Riemann tensor, these either vanish or are proportional to the tensors above.